# how can i append textbox based on dynamic created dropdown children on changes

Tags: jquery

i want to add child text boxes on the selection of child dropdown counting. I have try the separate code on jsfiddle which is working http://jsfiddle.net/hs7t8/ . There are two dropdown list are created on the selection of guest selection dropdown . it dynamically generates two drop down on add room button click. first one is adult and second is children. On the selection of children dropdown i want to text boxes accroding to the selection of the children dropdown. but it is not adding to page. please Help me out .complete running code on http://jsfiddle.net/pYRj3/1/

```
$('#guestsRoomsSelect').change(function () {

        if ($(this).val() === '0') {
               var $var2 = '<div id="dropdown2_ ' + (counter) + ' " class="class1"> <div class="wrapadults" style="float:left"> <label class="lbl_sm" style="font-size: 0.75em" for="adults">Adults</label>'
                $var2 = $var2 + '<br/><span> <span>     <select id="adults" class="t_adults" style="margin-left:7px;margin-right:7px; border-right: 0.5px solid #FFFFFF;">      <option value="1">1</option>        <option value="2" selected="selected">2</option>'
                $var2 = $var2 + '<option value="3">3</option>       <option value="4">4</option>        <option value="5">5</option>        <option value="6">6</option>        <option value="7">7</option>'
                $var2 = $var2 + '<option value="8">8</option>       <option value="9">9</option>        <option value="10">10</option>      </select>     </span>       </span>  </div>'
                $var2 = $var2 + '<div class="children" > <label class="lbl_sm" style="font-size: .75em;" for="children">Children</label><br/> <span>  <select id="hc_f_children" class="hc_evt_children " style="border-right: 0.5px solid #FFFFFF;">'
                $var2 = $var2 + '<option value="0" selected="selected">0</option> <option value="1">1</option> <option value="2">2</option> <option value="3">3</option>'
                $var2 = $var2 + '<option value="4">4</option> </select> </span>  </div>   </div>';
                $("#Addition").prepend('<fieldset id="' + counter + '" data-index="' + index + '">' + $var2 + '</fieldset>');
                counter = counter + 1;
                index++;

                $('#roomconfig').show(300);

        }
        else if ($(this).val() === '1-1' || $(this).val() === '3-1' || $(this).val() === '4-1' || $(this).val() === '2-2' || $(this).val() === '2-1') {

          $('#roomconfig').hide(300);

            $('#Addition fieldset :first').remove();  
        } });

    var forage = 0;
    $(".addRoom").click(function () {
        // on add room event

        var $var1 = '<div id="dropdown2_ ' + (counter) + ' " class="class1"> <div class="wrapadults" style="float:left"> '
        $var1 = $var1 + '<span> <span>      <select id="adults" class="t_adults" style="margin-left:7px;margin-right:7px; border-right: 0.5px solid #FFFFFF;">      <option value="1">1</option>        <option value="2" selected="selected">2</option>'
        $var1 = $var1 + '<option value="3">3</option>       <option value="4">4</option>        <option value="5">5</option>        <option value="6">6</option>        <option value="7">7</option>'
        $var1 = $var1 + '<option value="8">8</option>       <option value="9">9</option>        <option value="10">10</option>      </select>     </span>       </span>  </div>'
        $var1 = $var1 + '<div class="children" > <span>  <select id="hc_f_children_' + forage + '" class="hc_evt_children " style="border-right: 0.5px solid #FFFFFF;" onselect="getIdvalue()">'
        $var1 = $var1 + '<option value="0" selected="selected">0</option> <option value="1">1</option> <option value="2">2</option> <option value="3">3</option>'
        $var1 = $var1 + '<option value="4">4</option> </select> </span>  </div> <div id="chileage_'+forage+'" class="ch"></div>  </div>'
        $var1 = $var1 + '<div class="btnrmv" id="' + counter + '" > <a class="removeRoom " style=" width:30px; height:0px; margin:0px;left:200px;position:relative; top:-30px; background-image:none; color:#b11500;font-weight:normal;font-size:0.77em;" href="javascript:void(0);">remove<span></span> </a> </div>';

        $("#Addition").append('<fieldset id="' + counter + '" data-index="' + index + '"' + $var1 + '</fieldset>');

        counter++;
        index++;
        forage++;
        // for remove element
        $(".btnrmv").click(function () {
            $("#roomconfig fieldset#" + this.id).remove();
            counter--;

        });

        var Idvalue = null;
        // Add childage textbox
        function getIdvalue() {
            Idvalue = $('.hc_evt_children').attr("id");


        }

        $(Idvalue).change(function () {

            var index1 = $(".ch input").size();
            var requested = parseInt($(".hc_evt_children").val(), 5);

            if (requested > index1) {
                for (i = index1; i < requested; i++) {
                    var $ctrl = $('<input/>').attr({ type: 'text', name: 'text', value: '' });
                    $("#chileage_" + forage).append($ctrl);
                }
            }
            else if (requested < index1) {
                var x = requested - 1;
                $("#chileage_ input:gt(" + x + ")").remove();
            }
        });


    });
```

```
    <div class="btnWrap" style="clear:both;border-bottom: 0.5px solid #FFFFFF;">
```

Add room

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the attribute onselect when creaating your markup. It won't fire.

Instead, after appending the child dropdown list, bind the change event to the dropdown.
On Need More Room selected:
 **$('#hc_f_children').bind('change', function() { // your code here, which adds those textboxes });**

On Add room pressed:
 **$('#hc_f_children_'+ forage).bind('change', function() { // your code here, which adds those textboxes });**

Comment: I used this bind function but not running http://jsfiddle.net/pYRj3/1/ plz review this link ...and provide a link jsfiddle

Comment: I added this to your code, and put an alert box to popup with the id of the current child dropdown. You can extend the function to add the textboxes for the appropriate select box. http://jsfiddle.net/peNVH/3/